# how to display selected dropdown inner attributes from different model in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two different models store_item and indent.Relation is In Indent-`has_many :store_items` and In store_item-`belongs_to :indent`.
On indent form i have taken dropdown i.e is store_item_id when i save indent how can i display the store_item inner attributes with the selected one that is unit_price,batch_no,quantity.As if now its display all the store_items.

## Indent/new_indent

```
<%= form_for @indent, url:{controller: 'indents',action:'create_indent'} do |c|%>
          <fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3"><b>Indent No:</b></div>
              <%=c.text_field :indent_no, placeholder: "Indent No", class: "form-control",style:"width:250px"%>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3"><b>Expected Date:</b></div>
              <%= c.date_field :expected_date, :value => Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),class: "datepicker form-control",style:"width:250px" %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3"><b>Description</b></div>
              <%=c.text_field :description, class: "form-control",style: 'width:350px;height:100px'%>
            </div>

             <h3>Indent Items</h3>
             <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3"><b>Required</b></div>
              <%=c.text_field :required, placeholder: "Required", class: "form-control",style:"width:250px"%>
             </div>

            <div class ="control-group">
             <div class="col-md-3"><b>Issued Type</b></div>
              <div class ="control-group">
              <%=c.select(:issued_type, options_for_select([['Temporary','Temporary'],['Permanant','Permanant']]),{prompt: "Select Type"})%>
             </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-3"> <b>Store Item:</b></div>
              <td class="col-3"> <%= c.select :store_item_id,StoreItem.all.collect{|b| [b.item_name,b.id]},{:value => params[:unit_price] },{prompt:"select Item"}%></td>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4"> 
              <div class="form-actions">               
                <%= c.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-primary"%>
              </div>
            </div>
```

## Indent/index_index

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Indent No</th>
   <th>Store</th>
   <th>Expected Date</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>Required</th>
   <th>Issued Type</th>
   <th>Destroy Indent</th>
   <th>Item Name</th>
   <th>Unit Price</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>
   <th>Batch No</th>
   <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>  
   <%@indents.each do |i|%>
    <td><%= i.indent_no %></td>
    <td><%= @stores.name %></td>
    <td><%= i.expected_date%></td>
    <td><%= i.description %></td>
    <td><%= i.required %></td>
    <td><%= i.issued_type %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', destroy_indent_indent_path(i), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' },class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" %></td>

   <% @store_items.each do |s|%>
    <td><%= s.item_name%></td>
    <td><%= s.unit_price %></td>
    <td><%= s.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= s.batch_no %></td>
  </tr>
 <tbody>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

## Indent_controller

```
def index_indent 
 @store_items = StoreItem.find(params[:id])
 @indents = Indent.all
 @stores = Store.all
end

def new_indent
 @indent = Indent.new
 @store = Store.new
 @store_item = StoreItem.new
end

def create_indent
 @indent = Indent.new(indent_params)
 if @indent.save
  redirect_to index_indent_indents_path
 else
  render 'new_indent'
 end
end
```

Expected output:

```
Item Name:Marker Pens
Store Name:Kirti Store
Batch No:Batch2     
Quantity:200            
Unit Price:20
```

Comment: You want to show the selected store item in drop down ?

Comment: @Vishal No. when i select store_item from drop down how will i get its single values i.e is unit_price, batch_no, quantity. added expected output.

Comment: do u want to store item details in controller ?

Comment: Just want to display the store Item on indent-index page.

Comment: Why you not inserting the record in store items ??